# cannot insert the NULL value into the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to insert data into the database, but it's continuously showing me this error, even though I not writing the name of the column(MemID) in the first fields, rather I am trying to enter it separately like this

```
create table Member (
MemID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
FullName VARCHAR(50),
email VARCHAR(50),
gender VARCHAR(50),
Contact_Number VARCHAR(50),
Registration_Number VARCHAR(50),
User_S# INT
);

insert into Member (FullName, email, gender, Contact_Number, 
Registration_Number, User_S#) values ('Jemmy Joutapaitis', 
'jjoutapaitiscf@dailymail.co.uk', 'Male', '86-(804)800-8008', 
'3574884734839928', 449);
insert into Member (FullName, email, gender, Contact_Number, 
Registration_Number, User_S#) values ('Cleo Glynn', 'cglynncg@i2i.jp', 
'Male', '81-(694)548-5205', '5443114970343516', 450);
insert into Member (FullName, email, gender, Contact_Number, 
Registration_Number, User_S#) values ('Ivonne Deetlefs', 
'ideetlefsch@virginia.edu', 'Female', '86-(257)683-5628', 
'3571675846170605', 451);

insert into Member(MemID)
values('Mem0');
insert into Member(MemID)
values('Mem1');
insert into Member(MemID)
values('Mem2');
```

This code is giving me the error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MemID', table
>   'master.dbo.Member'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

But I am inserting MemID column separately.

And also the table which has created above is not showing in the database, is it because of the error or something else?

Comment: You don't *insert* a column value separate.  You have the hope of *updating* one, but not *inserting*.

Comment: 50 characters for an email is really too few, but it's also comically long for something ilke "gender". Hint: Use `VARCHAR(255)` by default unless you have a compelling reason to restrict it, like two-letter ISO country codes or something that's a standard, fixed length.

Comment: I am using fake data generator to generate the upper values of all columns, But for the MemID I am using a python script to generate values.

Comment: That's why i am not putting MemID with rest of the columns

Comment: Also having `#` in a column name is going to be trouble. I'm surprised that even executes without errors.

Comment: Put it in with the rest of the columns. Listen to what's being said here. Do you expect MySQL to not enforce the constraint you asked it to apply just because?

Comment: Isn't there's an another way around to counter this problem?

Comment: @sami try my answer

Comment: How exactly did you imagine that the server would know which of your separate `insert` statements were meant to update which rows from previous `insert` statements...

Answer (score 3):

That's not how inserts work.

When an insert is triggered sql tries to add the row immediately, without waiting for the consequent statements (it's stands true for any dml statements not only insert).

So when your first insert is triggered then sql is trying to put `null` in `MemID` as you haven't supplied any MemID in your insert.

Try inserting it in the very first place itself in the insert. Instead of separate statement something  like:

```
insert into Member (MemID, FullName, email, gender, Contact_Number, 
Registration_Number, User_S#) values ('Mem0','Jemmy Joutapaitis', 
'jjoutapaitiscf@dailymail.co.uk', 'Male', '86-(804)800-8008', 
'3574884734839928', 449);
```

**EDIT**

With response to your comment , I think Prepared statements is what you're looking for.

Since you're using python you could do prepare your insert statement like:

```
sql = "insert into Member (MemID, FullName, email, gender, Contact_Number, 
    Registration_Number, User_S#) values (%s,'Jemmy Joutapaitis', 
    'jjoutapaitiscf@dailymail.co.uk', 'Male', '86-(804)800-8008', 
    '3574884734839928', 449);"
sql = sql.format(self.db_scan_table)

//whenever you've memid ready use.
self.cursor.execute(sql, ('Mem01'))
```

Comment: I can't do that because I am generating MEMID data with the script and rest of the values with the fake data generator. And there are more than 450 lines of code, So, I can't append each line

Comment: then use prepared statements to accomplish what you're doing!!! look up online for prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Define an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column to generate ID values for you:

```
CREATE TABLE Member (
  MemID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  -- ...
);
```

If this isn't practical because you need some kind of particular string definition for these then your only option is to supply it as part of the initial `INSERT` call. You have a constraint here, the `PRIMARY KEY` value must not be `NULL`.

Comment: But I want primary key values to be like this "Mem0, Mem1, Mem2, Mem3... so on". How to do this with the increment statement?

Comment: Custom primary keys are often *way* more trouble than they're worth and are often a lot slower than a simple `INT` primary key. If you're committed to that approach you need to follow Nishanth's advice in the other answer.

Comment: Dude, I can't append a thousand lines of code, it would take much time. I need to have another way around

Comment: Dude, your busted code is not my problem. Fix it or deal. You're asking MySQL to do something you've told it not to do. Turn off your `PRIMARY KEY`, populate, then patch in the values you need after and restore the primary key if you must. Everything about this question is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

should be able to using the query below. identify the next number

```
insert into member(memid,......)
values ( 'MEM' + cast((select count(1) from member)+1 as varchar(100)),...   )
```

if you want to start with 1 then + 1 
otherwise remove + 1

```
insert into member(memid,......)
values ( 'MEM' + cast((select count(1) from member) as varchar(100)),...   )
```